# How to customize node format in ProjectLibre WBS view

Tags: work-breakdown-structure, projectlibre

I am teaching a class on project management and would like to guide my students toward experimenting with ProjectLibre. Part of the course requirements is to produce a WBS.

When I look at [YouTube videos WBS in ProjectLibre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKHhFm6bQvY), the nodes only contain the name of the task. However, in my verison (1.9.1) the WBS nodes include "Cost" and "Budget" items.

[image]

I would like to remove those items and only show the task name.

Is there a way to customize the node layout for ProjectLibre WBS nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to have no good news for you. You could theoretically change the layout in the source and recompile the jar files. In the video they use probably a version up to 1.61 or a customized build.
An open word from me personally: The project ProjectLibre moves at a very slow pace. Since 2012 to today they can not even match the old MS Project 97 with WBS chart pro extension. They create a lot of marketing fuzz as being the MS Project killer (now launching cloud services) but to be honest it does not look like they can even bite the little toe - which is a pity.
As a fan of open software its a shame that there is no real support, even questions in the community forums stay unanswerd and there is no open discussion about "features" like settings via menu and not bat files or folders and *.conf files where you just can change the language but not the time, date and currency format and that in a date/time/cost application. 
No possibility to add a custom WBS ID and responsible person (not even on task level) which is in certain PM Standards a must.
 For students this is/ may be ok. I use it too with my master students in PM but as the University also offers free MS teacher/student versions I'm also teaching MS Project (which I would gladly stop to do, but as written...)